# REST web service calling convention

Tags: rest, architecture

My web application (say A) will expose few REST services (GET, POST, and PUT) that will be meant for the use of other 2 web applications (say B & C). These services can be called by other web apps without logging in with A, at the same time these are for B & C only (may be for D, E additionally later).

Now since B & C user won't login with A, I am not thinking about session maintenance, however, I think A needs to authenticate whether the call is coming from B & C only. I can introduce `user id` and `password` in the REST signature for such external users (B & C), but wondering about the standard convention in such scenario. I'm looking for your suggestions.

App A is based on Spring, and Java with Spring REST. I am planning to introduce JWT for session.

Answer (score 0):

I thing that you have slightly messed up.

1. Never pass password in the url, because many servers log urls (**in plaintext**).
2. For securing Spring Application, I suggest using [Spring Security](https://howtotrainyourjava.com/2017/03/30/spring-security-basics/).
3. If you definitely don't want to maintain user sessions, you can generate API keys for each user and the user will attach that key to each request. Such API key might be generated by `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

Comment: Should the client store the API Key? Is that static?

Comment: Definitely not - you should keep keys in the db.

Comment: Thanks, What I mean is that, in order the "...user will attach that key to each request" the user has to know it. Should the user store the same key in client also. I understand that the key should be stored in DB, but how does the client know what is it's own key? I am missing something probably.

Comment: Compare with acu weather. You request the key, receive it via email and then attach as a param to reach request.

Comment: I am planning to implement like this: the server A will store the Client id, Client API Key (a unique message that represents the client B & C), and secret key in DB. Client will create a signature with secret+API key using hmac-sha256. Then it will send the signature and the Client Id through http authorization header.  Server will get the client id and find the corresponding secret and API key from db. It will create same hash and then check with the client signature. If it matches then it will allow the request.
Will this be Okay?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) and [JWT tokens](https://jwt.io/) as a solution to your current authentication/authorization flow.

in OAuth, you'd use an identity provider (iDP) to authenticate the user and issue a token with user info and claims than pass that token along to resource providers (APIs, Websites, etc) that trust the token issuer (iDP) and can verify the token validity.